# Android: Push bot sending a notification to certain group of registered devices

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, push

I have a question regarding pushbot! How can I send a push notification to a certain group of registered device's of those people who I'd like to receive the notification I pushed? 
Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html